# HTML history state issues on OS X Chrome 10.0.648.151

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, state, browser-history

I'm trying to figure out how to use HTML5's history functions. Here's my basic code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
    console.log(history.state);

    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
            console.log(e.originalEvent);
    });
});
```

I'm using Jquery 1.5.1. Here's the console output:

```
undefined

PopStateEvent
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
clipboardData: undefined
currentTarget: DOMWindow
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 2
returnValue: true
srcElement: DOMWindow
state: null
target: DOMWindow
timeStamp: 1300966328992
type: "popstate"
__proto__: PopStateEvent
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is the *history.state* undefined? Even in the *popstate* event nothing exists.
2. Why is *popstate* even called?! I never pressed back or forward. This is on the first load.

Hopefully somebody can shed some light on this for me.

Thanks in advance!

Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the FF team, `history.state` and *not* firing popstate on page-load are features of their browser.

Here's a quote from their notes, at http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/history-api-changes-in-firefox-4/

> - Always expose the current state through a window.history.state property. This way a page immediately gets access to the current state of the page and doesn’t have to wait until the first popstate event fires.
> - Don’t always fire a popstate event right after the load event.
>     Instead, only fire it during real session history transitions (i.e., when the user clicks Back or Forward or when history.back()/forward()/go() is called)

No matter the feature, it is frustrating when vendors split hairs on implementation. Thankfully you can handle the difference easily enough, by simulating the specification and firing your own popstate event on pageload.

Something like this should work in FF4 using jQuery. You would use this code after binding your event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (history.pushState && typeof history.state !== 'undefined') {
    $(window).trigger({
      type: 'popstate',
      state: history.state
    });
  }
});
```

This approach does favor the specification, but it consolidates state management to your handler function(s), instead of an initialization routine; which is easier to maintain. Honestly, I appreciate `history.state`, but it is superfluous as it's only useful during page load; otherwise it becomes another variable storage mechanism.

On a similar note, avoid calling `pushState()` initially. States are not a kind of variable and shouldn't be used as such. I only recommend setting the state while responding to a user action - that is *after* the page/app loads.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `history.state !== 'undefined'` is to detect Firefox? (i.e. if we are using a browser whose history.state is defined (even if it's null), then we know that the browser won't trigger popstate on load, so we need to simulate it?)