# window.onpopstate, event.state == null?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've read several question/answers on Stack Overflow and Googled the issue, I can't seem to get the `event.state` to come back with anything but `null`.

I got that it wont work with the jQuery event, but when I do something like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
     console.log(e.state)
}
```

With something along the lines of a jQuery.ajax success calling

```
history.pushState({ lastUrl: data.State }, data.Title, data.UrlKey);
```

Neither Chrome (v19) or Firefox (v12) return anything but null? Am I missing something? Is it just not fully implemented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML history state issues on OS X Chrome 10.0.648.151](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418540/html-history-state-issues-on-os-x-chrome-10-0-648-151)

Comment: @Derek the question you provided is talking about popstate firing upon pageload. To clarify, at any time popstate fires, none of the data sent from a pushState function (ie. lastUrl in the above example) is available in the event object, this is the issue I'm inquiring about

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`e.state` refers to the second last state that was pushed. You need to have pushed state at least twice for `e.state` to not be `null`. This is because you should save the state when your site is loaded the first time and thereafter every time it changes state.

Comment: Solved my problem I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107147/javascript-history-state-incorrect ... If you can write an answer for my question here, I can accept it.

Comment: General comment: I would recommend instead of overloading the function `window.onpopstate = function (e) {` simply "listen" to it `window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {`... because otherwise you'll cancel other implementation is has which you didn't re-write.

Comment: See my description of my problem with this same issue below.  I did call the pushState many times every time the user (me) clicked a link. But the state was still always null.  It only became non-null when I called pushState () "at least twice" IN THE ONLOAD-handler. I don't understand why calling it many times from the onclick -handler did not make it work. Did it perhaps have something to do with the 3rd argument to pushState() having a wrong value?  Who knows. Perhaps. But calling the pushState() twice in the onload -handler solved the problem.

Comment: Just to add to the answer above: instead of calling `pushState` twice, which adds 2 entries to history, I prefer to call `replaceState` w my desired state upon load. Then subsequent `pushState` calls work as expected.

Answer (score 20):

I think that this question needs a more clear explanation because the sentence "second last state that was pushed" in the other answers may lead to confusion.

When we do history.pushState we are pushing into the history stack a new State, that becomes the current one (as we can see from the navigation bar url.)

The window.onpopstate event means that the top history state is being popped out (taken away from the stack) , so the e.state will now point to the new new top state in the stack (as the navigation bar will point to the previous url).

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this same issue for many hours.
Too many hours. The state-argument of onpopstate -handler
was null even though I had called pushState()
many times before I clicked the back-button.

I also  observed that my onclick-handler which
called pushState() caused the onpopstate -handler
to be triggered. I believe onpopstate -handler 
should only get called due to user clicking on the
back-button from what I read on the web. But 
that seemed not to be the case in my case.

Could there be a bug in the browser? 
Seems unlikely because I had the same 
or similar  problem on both  Chrome and FireFox. 
But possible. Or maybe there is a "bug in the spec"
being too complicated to implement correctly.
No public unit-tests showing how this should work.

Finally I arrived at a solution after which 
EVERYTHING started working. It was to put 
these two calls into my onload-handler:

```
pushState (myInitialState, null, href);
pushState (myInitialState, null, href);
```

So I have to make the same push-state() call 
TWICE in the onload-handler!  After that my 
onpopstate -handler started getting arguments 
whose state was NOT null but a state I had
previously passed as argument to pushState().

I don't really understand why it now works and
why it didn't earlier when I called pushState ONLY 
ONCE.

I would like to understand why it works now but I 
already spent too much time with this getting 
it to work. If anybody has a reference to good 
example-code online which explains it that
would be great.

Comment: In my case popState would receive null state often (not always). Ensuring that there was an additional initial pushState call seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`history.state` is associated with the current page, so it's possible to `forward` and `back`. To get the first history's state, you can use `history.replaceState` to place in the state of the first history.

```js
window.history.replaceState(currentState, document.title)
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be helpful if you have ever learnt about the undo/redo stack, as the picture shows below.

[image]

In fact, the history is kept in a stack like this. Your current state is from current stack item, and let's assume there is a pointer to it; when you call `history.back()`, the pointer go to older item of the stack, the `onpopstate` event's state is the same as `history.state` by the way. You will just get the item which pointer currently pointing at, which modified by `history.replaceState` or added by `history.pushState`.

This process also explains why `history.length` doesn't change, because it represents the whole stack's length. When you call `history.go(1)`, the pointer move back to the newer item.

When the pointer is at a middle position of stack, calling `history.pushState` will lead to all the items above the pointer popped, and new one added, also you can see `history'length` changes.

Comment: And this explains the `null` value how?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, all the answers here are really confusing.

- you need to push or replace the initial state.
- popstate does not give you the second last state, but the last state.
- there is certainly no need to push the initial state twice.

I think what's confusing to everyone is that `event.state` will hold whatever value you set as the first (`data`) parameter in the `history.pushState()` call. If you set it to `null`, then sure enough your `event.state` will be null as well.

## Why don't you need to push the initial state?

The initial state is right there in your event, it just has no `data` set, so `event.state` will be `null`. What you are looking for to redirect back to the initial page is simply the `document.location` (because at the time of `popstate`, we are already at that location).

If you want full control, it is a good idea to replace the initial state with some meaningful `data` set, so you can be sure it's the state you expected without having to compare the document url.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaco Briers mentioned, for `popstate` to work the way we think it should work, we need to first store the initial state to return to when you click on the browser's Back button. Here's a sample implementation using jQuery:

**Sample Code**

```
$(window).on({
  // Store initial state
  'load': function() {
    window.history.pushState({
      'html': '<div id="ajax-content">' + $('#ajax-content').html() + '</div>'
    }, '', document.URL);
  },
  // Handle browser Back/Forward button
  'popstate': function(e) {
    var oState = e.originalEvent.state;
    if (oState) {
      $('#ajax-content').replaceWith(oState.html);
    }
  }
});

...

// Update AJAX content
var sUrl = 'https://www.example.com/category?id=123&format=ajax';
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: sUrl,
  success: function(sHtml) {
    $('#ajax-content').replaceWith(sHtml);
    window.history.pushState({
      'html': sHtml
    }, '', sUrl);
  }
});
```