# Laravel. Ajax Append

Tags: ajax, laravel

Is it possible to append something into another route ?

For example,

I had an input in `Order` page and once it submits, it will append the data in `Kitchen` Page and refreshes the content without refreshing the whole page itself.

**EDIT:** Can someone give an example syntax ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the HTML5 History Api.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23793006/1336174). I think that's what you're looking for.