# Show alert on Browser Back Button event on react js

Tags: reactjs

I have to show an alert on the browser back event on React js. I have tried using the `addEventListener` but I'm not sure where to place the code in the React page. Should I place in any life-cycle hooks or in the render? I'm not sure. Please help me out.

Comment: [Some example in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008806/how-to-detect-if-the-user-clicked-the-back-button)

Comment: I wanted to do it in React JS.

Comment: Exactly. You just need to adapt it. The examples are just to give you the event listener name

Comment: For example, I have a page called `payment.js` which renders the payment page view. So when the user tries to click browser back button on that page, can I show the alert that is written on the payment.js itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved by myself. I have given the explanation with the code below:

First, add the below code in either `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillMount` hook:

```
window.history.pushState({name: "browserBack"}, "on browser back click", window.location.href);
window.history.pushState({name: "browserBack"}, "on browser back click", window.location.href);
```

The reason why I'm pushing it twice is that the state will be updated only if it's pushed twice. Here's the [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092736/window-onpopstate-event-state-null). The above code will push the current page's URL in the history on the page load.

So when the back browser button is clicked the same page will be reloaded again since the history has been manipulated by the `pushState` method.

Then add the following code above the `pushState` method:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
  if (event.state) {
    //do your code here
  }
 }, false);
```

Now, when the **Browser back button** is clicked the above even listener will be called and since we updated the `state` which `pushState` method, the `if` will be true and you can do whatever you wanted to do in it.

Comment: it is working only first time. after that navigatiing back

Answer (score 16):

if you use react hooks you can use useEffect hooks to do it in following step

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const [finishStatus, setfinishStatus] = useState(false);

const onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!finishStatus) {
        if (window.confirm("Do you want to go back ?")) {
            setfinishStatus(true)
            // your logic
            props.history.push("/");
        } else {
            window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
            setfinishStatus(false)
        }
    }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);  
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this,

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
  alert("You message");
});
```

You can place it in `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()` as per your need.

[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)

Comment: I will try, but I have one more question. Will the `componeneWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()` hook be invoked on the browser back event?

Comment: @AshokRRaghu When you hit browser back button, your component will simply re-render so these methods will get execute.

Comment: I used but it shows only on the page load, not on the browser back button click.

Comment: For example, I have a page called `payment.js` which renders the payment page view. So when the user tries to click browser back button on that page, can I show the alert that is written on the `payment.js` itself?

Answer (score 2):

check out this link [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

The key points there:

```
document.onmouseover = function() {
    //User's mouse is inside the page.
    window.innerDocClick = true;
}

document.onmouseleave = function() {
    //User's mouse has left the page.
    window.innerDocClick = false;
}

window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
        //Your own in-page mechanism triggered the hash change
    } else {
        //Browser back button was clicked
    }
}
```

This prevents back space from being used to navigate back

```
 $(function(){
        /*
         * this swallows backspace keys on any non-input element.
         * stops backspace -> back
         */
        var rx = /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i;

        $(document).bind("keydown keypress", function(e){
            if( e.which == 8 ){ // 8 == backspace
                if(!rx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly ){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried so many solutions but none of working in my case and after I find this

```js
componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this._confirm);
        window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        window.onpopstate = this._backConfirm;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this._confirm);
        window.onpopstate = () => { }
    }

    _backConfirm = async () => {
        let event = window.confirm("Changes that you may not be saved.");
        if(event){
            window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        }
    }

    _confirm = (e) => {
        var confirmationMessage = "\o/";
        e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution and it is working fine for me.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        onClickBackButton: false
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
   window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
   window.addEventListener('popstate', this.onClickBackButton);
}

onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.onClickBackButton) {

        if (window.confirm("Do you want to go back without submitting details?")) {
            this.onClickBackButton= true;
            // your custom logic to page transition,like react-router-dom 
            history.push()
        } else {
            window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
            this.onClickBackButton= false;
        }
    }
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.onClickBackButton);
}
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984563/11181109)

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with accessing state in event listener, using ref helped.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const [finishStatus, _setfinishStatus] = useState(false);

const finishStatusRef = React.useRef(isUpdated);
const setfinishStatus = data => {
  finishStatusRef.current = data;
  _setfinishStatus(data);
};

const onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!finishStatusRef.current) {
        if (window.confirm("Do you want to go back ?")) {
            setfinishStatus(true)
            // your logic
            props.history.push("/");
        } else {
            window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
            setfinishStatus(false)
        }
    }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);  
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

With the React router dom version 4 and 5 (I personally tested with version 5, and it worked just perfectly), you have a very easy way of doing this. Just import the Prompt from react-router-dom, and you can conditionally show the browser alert with a custom message:

instead of `when={true}`. Feel free to replace the true with a **state** with the type boolean to enable or disable this functionality.

```
import { Prompt } from "react-router-dom";

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Prompt when={true} message="are you sure you want to leave this page?" />

      {/* REST OF YOUR CODE LOGIC */}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```